# Hover on a element in Appium

Tags: javascript, java, appium, ui-automation

I am trying to hover on a link element using appium. This is for iOS device on sauce. Unfortunately I'm unable to do it at all.

I tried the below java code and it doesn't work:

```
Actions action = new Actions(appium);                
action.moveToElement(appium.findElement(element)).moveToElement(appium.findElement(element)).build().perform();
```

Webdriver works but not appium.
Could some please provide me a solution for this?

Comment: what is `appium` here? share the full code

Comment: @nullpointer -  I'm surprised you ask what is appium. Here you go http://appium.io/

Comment: If someone could share me javascriptexecutor for this hover operation for appium, it would be so helpful.

Comment: Don't be! Because I am asking you about the variable used in the code not the application. :)

Comment: @nullpointer - sorry misunderstood you. Here it is:`AppiumDriver appium = new IOSDriver(new URL(URL), caps);`

Comment: if you have found any solution to this please share

Answer (score 0):

@Eajaz Not sure if this issue still exists for you. Even I faced this issue and tried various things and finally found that the below thing works.

```
action.moveToElement(appium.findElement(element)).moveToElement(appium.findElement(element)).release();
```

Also, I couldn't find any `executescript` command for `mousehover` in the `XCUITest` library. Below is the link I'm referring to.
http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/#ios-xcuitest-only